# DataTable com métodos construtores de uma classe para fazer cadastros

Tags: c#, datatable

Estou tentando fazer um `DataTable` que salva dados (não estou usando banco de dados) referentes a nome e e-mail de um cliente e exibe em um `DataGridView` (exibir na grid não é o problema, isso eu sei fazer) os dados que foram digitados na `textbox`.
Comecei a mexer com `DataTable` ontem e li que ele é melhor para a minha aplicação do que uma `List<T>`, que eu já usei para fazer adição e exclusão em um programa de cadastros.

Abaixo coloquei o código da classe Dados e os seus atributos e métodos, mas gostaria de receber uma ajuda para entender como pegar o método da minha classe (que no caso é o Nome que é digitado na text box `txt_nome` e o `Email` que é recebido na `txt_email`) e colocar ele dentro da `DataTable`. Abaixo coloquei as partes do código que eu já tenho e são relevantes:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Cadastro");
```

..........

```
private void bt_salvar_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Nome"] = txt_nome.Text;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

...............

```
public class Dados
{

    private string _nome;
    private string _email;

    //construtor para iniciar os dados privados - recebe parametros
    public Dados(string nome, string email)
    {
        this._nome = nome;

        this._email = email;
    }


    public string Nome
    {
        get
        {
            return _nome;
        }
        set
        {
            _nome = value;
        }
    }

    public string Email
    {
        get
        {
            return _email;
        }
        set
        {
            _email = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Se eu estiver falando alguma bobagem me desculpem, sou iniciante e estou tentando aprender bem tudo da melhor forma (estou procurando vários pontos de vista sobre cada assunto de c#).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se é exatamente o que você queria, mas coloquei abaixo um exemplo usando sua classe `Dados`

```
private void bt_salvar_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
        //No segundo parâmetro, que está vazio, você pode colocar o email
        //digitado em algum textbox, por exemplo.
        Dados dados = new Dados(txt_nome.Text, "");
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

        //Aqui, em vez de pegarmos direto da textbox, pegamos do atributos
        //do objeto que declaramos logo acima
        dr["Nome"] = dados.Nome;

        //Você também poderia, por exemplo, colocar o email em alguma coluna        
        //dr["Email"] = dados.Email;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Caso queira ler os dados depois, pode percorrer o `DataGrid`, lendo suas linhas e preenchendo os objetos.

Comment: Exatamente isso, muito obrigado!!